# How I can do the context sensitive menu for example in codemirror?

Tags: codemirror

I am using codemirror5.1 , I need to make context sensitive menu for example in codemirror , so can any body provide me with example How to make context sensitive menu for example in codemirror ?? 
Edit : I want to Edit the context of context sensitive menu by add event to it for example I want to add to the menue the word (show sample) and when I press on it then an event fired, so can I do it or Not ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done to research this before asking the question? As written, your question is too broad.

Comment: I only need to context sensitive menu  show when I press (right click by mouse) and then I will control in context of the menu by my self @Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 3):

[djibe89's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/qej2ppcq/) shows how to create a contextmenu. This can be applied to CodeMirror.

```html
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm" id="context-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
```

```js
        $('.CodeMirror').on('contextmenu', function(e) {

            var top = e.pageY - 10;
            var left = e.pageX - 90;

            $("#context-menu").css({
                 display: "block",
                 top: top,
                 left: left
            }).addClass("show");

            return false; 

         }).on("click", function() {

            $("#context-menu").removeClass("show").hide();

         });
```